# How to get RecordingUrl after call complete in status call Back Url in Twilio in .net Core?

Tags: twilio, asp.net-core-webapi, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

After a successful call completion, I want to store the call status, duration, and recording URL of the call in my database, i have created an API for the status call back URL and put it into to Twilml App. in the status call back url section with post method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> statuscallback()
{
    Response response = new Response();
    Exception exception = new Exception();

    NotImplementedException _defaultEx = new NotImplementedException("No exception has been passed to the log method");

    StatusCallResponse statusCallResponse = new StatusCallResponse();
    statusCallResponse.CallDuration = HttpContext.Request.Form["CallDuration"].FirstOrDefault();
    statusCallResponse.CallStatus = HttpContext.Request.Form["CallStatus"].FirstOrDefault();
    statusCallResponse.SipResponseCode = HttpContext.Request.Form["SipResponseCode"].FirstOrDefault();
    statusCallResponse.RecordingDuration = HttpContext.Request.Form["RecordingDuration"].FirstOrDefault();
    statusCallResponse.RecordingSid = HttpContext.Request.Form["RecordingSid"].FirstOrDefault();
    statusCallResponse.RecordingUrl = HttpContext.Request.Form["RecordingUrl"].FirstOrDefault();
    string patientId = HttpContext.Request.Query["patientId"].ToString();

    CallRecordingAdd add = new CallRecordingAdd();
    add.RecordingSid= statusCallResponse.RecordingSid;
    add.RecordingUrl = statusCallResponse.RecordingUrl;
    add.Timestamp = statusCallResponse.RecordingDuration;
    add.PatientId =patientId;

    response = await _twilioCallService.CallRecordingAddAsync(add).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.Message = "call connected";

    return Ok(response);
}
```